# Categorize ArrayList of objects based on their property

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList of Products, and each Product has a category as a property (so each category can have many products). I just need to format the data so that the products are categorized according to the category property.

I would think that a HashMap would be useful, as I could just use the category as the key and the ArrayList of products as the value.

If this is the correct approach, can someone assist me with the logic involved in turning my ArrayList into the HashMap as I have described? Or maybe there is a better way of handling it.

/** Update **/

Here is a sample method, but I'm not exactly sure how to make the logic happen:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList> sortProductsByCategory (ArrayList<Product> productList) {

    // The hashmap value will be the category name, and the value will be the array of products
    HashMap<String, ArrayList> map;

    for(Product product: productList) {

        // If the key does not exist in the hashmap
        if(!map.containsKey(product.getCategory()) {
            // Add a key to the map, add product to new arraylist
        }
        else {
            // add the product to the arraylist that corresponds to the key
        }
        return map;

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you want to print them that way, or store them somewhere that way?

Comment: Your approach appears sound. Show us the code where you're trying to create a `HashMap` and tell us what you're having trouble with.

Comment: [Apache Commons JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/) or [Guava Predicate](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) probably !

Comment: In fact you'll need a Map<Category, List<Product>>. If you use Guava, consider using a ListMultimap<Category, Product> instead. It's easier to use and populate.

Comment: _"format the data so that the products are categorized according to the category property"_ -- This is rather meaningless given the information you've provided.  You will need to be much more explicit about what you want to do.

Comment: @RohitJain - I don't need to store them, just display them

Comment: @jwburnside. Then you can simply sort the list based on the `category`. You can write a `Comparator` for that. But, if you are doing it many times, you are better off with the `Map` approach.

Comment: @Jeffry Updated the question with a clearer example of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a better way of doing this, but it seems to work for me:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>> sortProductsByCategory (ArrayList<Product> arrayList) {

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>();

    for(Product product: arrayList) {

        // If the key does not exist in the hashmap
        if(!map.containsKey(product.getCategory().getName())) {
            ArrayList<Product> listInHash = new ArrayList<Product>();
            listInHash.add(product);
            map.put(product.getCategory().getName(), listInHash);
        } else {
            // add the product to the arraylist that corresponds to the key
           ArrayList<Product> listInHash = map.get(product.getCategory().getName());
           listInHash.add(product);

        }

    }

    return map;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely valid approach as you want to switch from "1-dimensional" view to "2-dimensional".